# Spring WebClient with OAuth2 is not storing access token

Tags: java, spring-boot, oauth-2.0, spring-webflux, spring-webclient

I have WebClient in my Spring Boot application that connects to the external service via OAuth2, and the configuration of it looks like following:

```
@Configuration
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class OAuth2ClientConfiguration {

    private final OAuth2ClientProperties properties;

    @Bean
    ReactiveClientRegistrationRepository clientRegistration() {

        ClientRegistration registration = ClientRegistration
                .withRegistrationId(properties.getClientRegistrationId())
                .tokenUri(properties.getTokenUri())
                .clientId(properties.getClientId())
                .clientSecret(properties.getClientSecret())
                .authorizationGrantType(new AuthorizationGrantType(properties.getAuthorizationGrantType()))
                .build();

        return new InMemoryReactiveClientRegistrationRepository(registration);
    }

    @Bean
    WebClient webClient(ReactiveClientRegistrationRepository clientRegistration) {

        var clientService = new InMemoryReactiveOAuth2AuthorizedClientService(clientRegistration);
        var authorizedClientManager = new AuthorizedClientServiceReactiveOAuth2AuthorizedClientManager(clientRegistration, clientService);

        var oauth = new ServerOAuth2AuthorizedClientExchangeFilterFunction(authorizedClientManager);
        oauth.setDefaultClientRegistrationId(properties.getClientRegistrationId());

        return WebClient.builder()
                .filter(oauth)
                .build();
    }
}
```

and here is an access token:

```
{
   "access_token": "some_generated_access_token",
   "token_type": "bearer",
   "expires_in": 82822,
   "scope": "api",
   "jti": "6e1a8d7c-3909-4acf-9168-cf912fcd0c8a"
}
```

It is working and everything is Ok, but... it is not storing the access token after it gets it, it is getting new access token each time it is called. I figured it out when launching my integration tests and verifying Authorization Server calls. However in configuration shown above it should store in memory.

I found out in internet this kind of problem can occur with SpringBoot version up to 2.2.3 and "org.springframework.security:spring-security-oauth2-client:5.2.1.RELEASE"

But I am using newest version of the Spring Boot 2.4.9, and it uses org.springframework.security:spring-security-oauth2-client:5.4.7

How can this issue be solved?

Comment: Are you sure the token doesn’t expire? Do you need to configure the refresh token?

Comment: @BoristheSpider I have added access token sample to my question now. Regarding refresh token, I thought that Spring will automatically renew it when expires

Comment: Not sure - possibly with autoconf; but you're manually configuring. The behaviour is provided by the `ReactiveOAuth2AuthorizedClientProvider` in `AuthorizedClientServiceReactiveOAuth2AuthorizedClientManager` which is `DEFAULT_AUTHORIZED_CLIENT_PROVIDER` unless configured - it defaults to a `clientCredentials()` grant only. If it's any help [here](https://gitlab.com/bmorris591/tado-influx/-/blob/master/src/main/kotlin/uk/co/borismorris/tado/TadoInfluxApplication.kt#L214) is a working configuration.